# How to display/manipulate an indexed image Octave

Tags: octave

Situation: Trying to output and also manipulate an indexed image.

Problem: When using `ind2rgb(image, colormap(x))`, we received an error saying that the `indexed image contains colors outside of colormap`, where `x` is the colormap option.

Question: How to work around this?

Additional information: I used `imshow(image, colormap(x))`, where I used every colormap available on Octave in substitution of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this happens because you have more indexes than colors in colormap. Just make a bigger colormap. You can do that with the sysntax `colormap(x(size_of_cmap))`

```
ind2rgb(image, colormap(viridis(max(image(:))))
```

Alternatively, create the colormap and interpolate it. Caution: this can create artifacts in the color due to HSVs circular behavior.

```
m=max(image(:));
cm=colormap(x);

hsv=rgb2hsv(cm);
cm=interp1(linspace(0,1,size(cm,1)),hsv,linspace(0,1,m));
cm=hsv2rgb(cm);

ind2rgb(image,cm);
```

I suggest using the first solution if possible.